# Property not found on ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, properties

I am beginning in iOS development. I've been searching a solution for days and I can't get it. I got the following code:

```
@interface SAProfileViewController : UITableViewController {
    @public NSNumber *userId;
}

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *awesomeProfileHeader;

    @property (nonatomic, assign) NSNumber *userId;

@end
```

As you can see I am declaring my property, and after that I do this :

```
@implementation SAProfileViewController

@synthesize userId = _userId;

...
```

On an other ViewController I import SAProfileViewController.

```
#import "SAProfileViewController.h"
...

-(void)goToUserProfile :(id) sender
{
   UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = (UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender;

   SAProfileViewController *controller = [[SAProfileViewController alloc] init];

   controller.userId = gesture.view.tag; // << HERE THE ERROR APPEARS

   [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

That's it, this is my code and I get the following error:
"Property 'userId' not found on object of type 'SAProfileViewController *'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Uhm. Clean the project? Also: it will crash once you get to compile it. Look at the types of `controller.userId` and `gesture.view.tag`.

Answer (score 2):

You have done a mistake with the property type.

Change

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSNumber *userId;
```

to

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *userId;
```

Than you have to create a `NSNumber` instance of `gesture.view.tag` like this

```
controller.userId = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:gesture.view.tag];
```

OR you can change your userId to `NSInteger` instead of `NSNumber*`

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger userId;
```

(you have to do this for the object attribute `userId`, too)

Comment: I tried all you said, but I continue on getting the same error, it seems that it's invisible. I am lost.

Comment: Can you say which error occurs? It is a compile error or is an exception thrown?

Comment: Can you try to remove `@public NSNumber *userId;` completely? Can you try to only use the property and do not declare an additional attribute?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/7Y5KMqF5 << Here is the first UIViewController, the one that calls SAProfileViewController

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Lw22PYCQ << Here is SAProfileViewController.h
http://pastebin.com/3YR1qZ5Y << Here is SAProfileViewController.h
See if I did something wrong, please.

Comment: The classes seem to be correct. If you use ARC you should change `retain` to `strong` but that would not change anything with your problem, I guess. Anyway, it must be `controller.userId = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:gesture.view.tag];` when you want to use your `userId` as `NSNumber`.

Comment: unfortunately I did all of the things I searched and even those you suggested me, and I couldn't solve my problem :/